# Initialysing didUpdateUserLocation in tab application with CLLocation

Tags: ios, tabbar, cllocation

I have this tab bar application with a map view component on the 3rd tab. This method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

is only being call after the user has view/open the 3rd tab, subsequently the user can move around the app and when his location changes the method is being called. My problem is I would like to ininialyse/enable the calls on that method with out the user having visit/initialyse the 3rd tab on the startup of the app... can you programaticaly force instantiation of a view controller before the user taps on the tab ?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to temporarily select the 3rd tab and then go back to the 1st tab in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;  //force init/load of 3rd tab
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;  //go back to 1st tab
```

The user should not see the momentary switch.